# KStream from one cluster to many

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I need to have one java module in my Kafka cluster that will get a message, and depending on two fields of the message, it would be enriched and published to another kafka cluster. I've been researching KStream API and I can't find a way to send things to another cluster (without using the publisher library).

Any ideas and how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out Kafka Connect and leverage "Single Message Transforms" that allow for filtering messages, too.

Comment: I agree with Matthias. Since the Confluent Replicator is a Kafka Connector you can even do the SMT right in the same tool that also does the replication from one cluster to another (instead of using Mirror Maker which does not do filtering it transforms/enrichment as it's replicated data)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will do some testing today and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to have one java module in my Kafka cluster that will get a message, and depending on two fields of the message, it would be enriched and published to another kafka cluster. I've been researching KStream API and I can't find a way to send things to another cluster (without using the publisher library).

At the moment, the Kafka's Streams API interacts only with one given cluster at a time.  That is, you cannot read from Kafka cluster A and then write to Kafka cluster B with the Streams API.

> Any ideas and how can I do this?

I'd therefore recommend to use Kafka Connect for this.  The latest versions of Kafka include the so-called [Single Message Transformations](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) feature in Kafka Connect, which you can use for such routing of messages.

If you are open to use a commercial tool, [Confluent Replicator](https://www.confluent.io/product/multi-datacenter/) ([docs](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-replicator/docs/index.html)) allows you to do such cross-cluster data flows, as Hans Jespersen mentioned above.

A good high-level starting point would be the talk [Single Message Transformations Are Not the Transformations You’re Looking For](https://kafka-summit.org/sessions/single-message-transformations-not-transformations-youre-looking/) (don't be deterred by the title :-P) by Ewen Cheslack-Postava, one of the Kafka committers who developed the new SMT feature.  There's also a [blog post](http://blog.dbvisit.com/trying-out-single-message-transformations-smt-in-kafka-connect/) that briefly describes SMT in Kafka Connect.

Comment: I haven't find a good way to use the SMT with this case, since the SMT waits for a Tranformation and expects a record being returned, and i want to consume them and erase them. I'm implementing a connector/plugin for kafka connect implementing SinkConnector, i have to go over the list of messages but seems more appropriate for this use case.